# PHP Session ID being regenerated automatically

Tags: php, session, session-cookies

I have found that on my simple web application, if you leave the page alone for more than about five minutes and then reload the page, calling session_id() will return a different value the second time. Users remain logged in, so the session data is being moved across to the new ID, but I keep track of cart items in a MySQL database based on the session ID, and when the ID changes, the association with the cart items is lost.

Nowhere in my code do I ever call session_regenerate_id()

Help!

Comment: What kind of hosting do you have? Shared server?

Comment: I assume you are calling `session_start()` accordingly - i.e. before page load.

Comment: You should probably look at your session expiration timeframe 'session.gc_maxlifetime' value.  It may be too short.

Comment: @MikeB it is on a shared server, yes

Comment: @JasonMcCreary yes, I am calling session_start before page load. It's worth noting that when the ID number changes, users are not logged out, it's as though session_regenerate_id() is being called, but I've double checked the code and we don't use that function anywhere.

Comment: @MikeBrant it's set to "session.gc_maxlifetime 1440". I've seen the ID change with less than five minutes between reloads. But users are not logged out, as I would expect if the session had expired, they are just assigned a new session ID and the session carries on as if nothing had happened. Indeed, the only reason it's a problem, is that we store cart items with their session_id for not-logged-in users.

Comment: hard to say in a shared server environment.  There could be sometihng on the machine itself that is removing files from the /tmp directory or wherever your specified session storage directory is.  You may want to look at using DB backed session if you want better control.

Comment: Make sure cookies are enabled.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check your code to see if you are using session_id() with an argument anywere as this will also change the session id. Without seeing the code it is hard to be specific as to a fix or to know what is going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Few more things you might want to check if encountered such situation AND you do use session_name():

1. From [PHP Online Manuals](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-name.php):

> Warning! The **session name can't consist of digits only**, at least one letter must be present.

2. Make sure you dont have spaces in your session_name() argument like

> **session_name('blah blah')**

Both situations force a new session id generated every time.